# Adding events to elements of an array

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to make a loop inside an array, and add events to its elements, not succeeding.
This is the array:

```
div_empresa_links_elements.push({
    div_mouseover: div_imagens_mouseover,
    div_submenu: div_empresa_imagens,
    div_txt: div_imagens_txt
}, {
    div_mouseover: div_institucional_mouseover,
    div_submenu: div_empresa_institucional,
    div_txt: div_institucional_txt
}, {
    div_mouseover: div_localizacao_mouseover,
    div_submenu: div_empresa_localizacao,
    div_txt: div_localizacao_txt
}, {
    div_mouseover: div_infraestrutura_mouseover,
    div_submenu: div_empresa_infraestrutura,
    div_txt: div_infraestrutura_txt
}, {
    div_mouseover: div_politicaDeQualidade_mouseover,
    div_submenu: div_empresa_politicaDeQualidade,
    div_txt: div_politicaDeQualidade_txt
}, {
    div_mouseover: div_linhaDoTempo_mouseover,
    div_submenu: div_empresa_linhaDoTempo,
    div_txt: div_linhaDoTempo_txt
}, {
    div_mouseover: div_historico_mouseover,
    div_submenu: div_empresa_historico,
    div_txt: div_historico_txt
})
```

This is the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < div_empresa_links_elements.length; i++) {
    var obj = div_empresa_links_elements[i]
    obj.div_mouseover.onmouseover = function () {
        obj.div_txt.style.opacity = 1
        obj.div_txt.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = 100)'
        obj.div_submenu.style.opacity = .7
        obj.div_submenu.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = 70)'
    }
}
```

The thing just works, if I put an event for each of the elements (_mouseover), by hand without a loop. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: If they are all supposed to do the same thing when you mouse over them then why not write one mouse over function and have them all reference the same function? It does not make sense to have a function inside of a for loop you don't need to create a dozen functions to do the same thing. Which is what your current code is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by a closure issue. Currently, `obj` is overwritten at each iteration. So, `obj` points to the lastly defined element. To fix this, wrap the the loop's body in a self-invoking function, and pass the variable `obj` as an argument, as shown below:

```
 for (var i = 0; i<div_empresa_links_elements.length;i++){
    var obj = div_empresa_links_elements[i]
    (function(obj){ //obj is declared again. Inside this func, obj = <see below>
        obj.div_mouseover.onmouseover = function(){
            obj.div_txt.style.opacity = 1
            obj.div_txt.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = 100)'
            obj.div_submenu.style.opacity = .7
            obj.div_submenu.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = 70)'
        }
    })(obj); //Pass the variable obj as defined at the top
}
```